# Set AUTH_USER_MODEL from apps inside folder from settings.py

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I'm new to django and I'm trying to extend the user class in one of my apps but I'm having trouble redirecting from setting.py to the model that contains my AbstractUser

My Nproject:

```
  -apps:
   --profile:
    ---__init__.py
    ---apps.py
    ---forms.py
    ---models.py
    ---urls.py
    ---views.py
   --apps1
 -media 
 -static    
 -templates 
 -Nproject:
  --__init__.py
  --settings.py
  --urls.py
  --wsgi.py
```

model in apps.profile.models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.email, self.username)
```

setting.py and here I think this is my mistake

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'apps.User'   #not working
```

I think the error is in AUTH_USER_MODEL that I do not know how to properly reference the model User

Research some sites and tell me that you should use the **init**.py file but it is not working

**init** in apps.profile

```
from .models import User
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                          
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>                                                                                                                  
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)                                                                                                                     
  File "/home/projects/.virtualenvs/Nproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line            
    utility.execute()                                                                                                                                       
  File "/home/projects/.virtualenvs/Nproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute                              
    django.setup()                                                                                                                                          
  File "/home/projects/.virtualenvs/Nproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup                                                 
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)                                                                                                                  
  File "/home/projects/.virtualenvs/Nproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate                                         
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)                                                                                                                    
  File "/home/projects/.virtualenvs/Nproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/home/projects/.virtualenvs/Nproject/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/projects/Nproject/apps/perfil/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .models import User
  File "/home/projects/Nproject/apps/perfil/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/home/projects/.virtualenvs/Nproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/projects/.virtualenvs/Nprojects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/projects/.virtualenvs/Nproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 100, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/projects/.virtualenvs/Nproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 244, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/projects/.virtualenvs/Nproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 127, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Additional data:
-Django 2.1
-Python 3.6.5

Answer (score 1):

The correct name string for the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` would be appname.modelname. In your case, I suppose it is `'profile.user'` (it could be different if you changed the app name by yourself)